# I have downloaded large gzipped xml files from Pubchem but my computer says they are corrupted

Tags: google-chrome, ftp, wget, file-corruption, gzip

I have tried twice downloading the large gzipped xml files from [PubChem FTP server](ftp://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubchem/Compound/CURRENT-Full/XML/), once through wget and one through chrome manually, but both times result in a corrupt file. For example, the first one and its MD5 hash file are here:

```
Compound_000000001_000500000.xml.gz
Compound_000000001_000500000.xml.gz.md5
```

Opening the MD5 file I see this:

```
be9a076090e9b263611c1fc7acf139a6  Compound_000000001_000500000.xml.gz
```

But running the commands on the xml.gz file I see this:

```
$ md5 Compound_000000001_000500000.xml.gz
MD5 (Compound_000000001_000500000.xml.gz) = 6eb5713212c085a1af89b0e31f09f9b9
$  gunzip -tv Compound_000000001_000500000.xml.gz
gunzip: data stream error
gunzip: Compound_000000001_000500000.xml.gz: uncompress failed
Compound_000000001_000500000.xml.gz:  NOT OK
```

So the MD5 hashes don't seem to match...

Same if I try and unpack the file using the built-in Mac functionality/app, it says error it was corrupted. I got no errors during downloading.

What is happening? I contacted someone at PubChem who said they were fine and the MD5 checked out correctly. Is there some browser setting I am unaware of or a router setting that is getting in the way? How do I fix this so the file isn't corrupted?

I can stream the gzipped file using Node.js through a gunzipper, and I see the XML, so it is at least partially correct. But it throws an error 10 or so seconds into parsing the file as well.

Could anything weird be happening?

Comment: Try [Keka](https://www.keka.io/en/) (donationware, ie free from the website, paid from the App Store) It often has a better chance at slightly non-standard files than the built-in Unarchiver

Comment: Tested the first file with both Unarchiver & Keka - both failed. `Error code 2 using "p7zip"
Fatal error`

Comment: md5 doesn't match either theirs or yours. `MD5 (/Volumes/Downloads/test keka/Compound_000000001_000500000.xml.gz) = 1ed5573b5b56b76418a1d69920b2e70e`

Comment: Then it's definitely something on the server's side.

Comment: It seems to work with an HTTPS url instead of an FTP one. https://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubchem/Compound/CURRENT-Full/XML/Compound_000000001_000500000.xml.gz Not sure why all of a sudden though.

Comment: FTP download timing out, producing a truncated file? Compare file sizes.

Comment: It works for me with the FTP link in the question using Firefox and 7-Zip, so there is nothing wrong with the .gz file.

Comment: @LancePollard using HTTPS as you suggests works, maybe add this as answer. Independently I guess this is an issue with pubmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information you have supplied I am going to say that I think that the file is actually corrupted. I would report to whatever website that you are trying to do it and notify them of this. Also, if you have wine installed (Or a windows computer) try to use 7-zip. If 7-zip says error then I know it is actually corrupted.

Comment: The file is not corrupted - I successfully downloaded and extracted it.

Comment: It was definitely corrupted, but maybe they fixed it.